# Purpose of \n in JSON request

Tags: android, json

I am learning about requesting a `JSON` request to fetch the data from the `internet` or `JSON` response. My mentor added `builder.append("\n");`this line without any need because my app is requesting and fetching data with and without this line perfectly. So can you tell me the purpose of this line?

```
 while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null){
                    builder.append(line);
                    builder.append("\n");
                }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***Welcome to StackOverFlow***

```
 builder.append("\n");
```

Since it's `JSON`, adding a `newline` ("\n")  isn't necessary (it won't affect parsing) but it does make `debugging` a *lot* easier if you print out the completed buffer for `debugging`.

Comment: How can i check the difference then?

Comment: Simply by printing them in logcat.

Comment: Thanks, i got it